# Can I search for someone on Facebook by their college/workplace without knowing their name?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

So, I have this coworker of mine that I wasn't very close to and would like to find her. I know that she worked at this specific business as well as went to a certain college but I have no idea what her first or last name is.

I've tried clicking 'People' on search results but it brings up nothing even when I put her workplace and college in.

Is it possible to search for someone purely by their workplace/college without knowing their name?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to search for someone by their workplace or college. But there is no guarantee that it will show up, because you are not sure if that person has added workplace/college in their profile. Even if they have added but not made it public, means kept it private or just to show friends who are already in their list.

If their profile is not public, you will not be able to search that person with their private profile information.